# Is it possible to run a sql query when azure VM starts?

Tags: mysql, azure, cron, schedule, azure-vm

Every day after turning on azure VM I'm executing one SQL query.
ie,
*SET GLOBAL sql_mode=(SELECT REPLACE(@@sql_mode,'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY',''));*
and also I have to restart my ngnix service after running this query.

I'm planning to do this using a bash script and will schedule a run for the same bash script using a cronjob.
Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: There is a way to execute SPs everytime the SQL Server starts, using [this](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1574/automatically-running-stored-procedures-at-sql-server-startup/), not sure if mySql has such mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can try it with the bash script, that is the best option.

Apart from that, as mentioned by @Anand in comment section, you can try to make Automatically Running Stored Procedures at SQL Server Startup.

Refer this [third party tutorial](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1574/automatically-running-stored-procedures-at-sql-server-startup/) for the same.